# Remove space between two views in chained view in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using chained view in constraint layout. Now I want the intermediate space between two text views to be removed.As the buttons at the bottom are at distance. I am trying to move them from design layout but its not happening as well. How to do it.Following is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout2">-->


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <!-- </LinearLayout>-->

    <!--  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout"
       >-->


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="213dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHeader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="89dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <!-- </LinearLayout>-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

At the bottom there are two text views,placed horizontally and there is space between them. Thanks much :)

Comment: Any reason for downvote ?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I dont understand downvotes too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `Guideline`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout2">-->


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <!-- </LinearLayout>-->

    <!--  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout"
       >-->


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="213dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewHeader" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline1"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="63dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline1" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <!-- </LinearLayout>-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

About Guideline in ConstraintLayout:
*Utility class representing a Guideline helper object for ConstraintLayout. Helper objects are not displayed on device (they are marked as View.GONE) and are only used for layout purposes. They only work within a ConstraintLayout. [...]*

For more details, there is good documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html

Comment: Thanks much :) There is some margin added in textview 5 while moving on desin layout as margin start ,but even when I remove it,there is still some space left between two text views. :)

Comment: @Pritish I have udpated my answer with contraint layout

Comment: Thanks , can you please elaborate about guideline ?

Comment: @Pritish Done. If I helped you, please upvote my answer and check as corrected to close the question. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 22):

To remove space between two chained view, simply add the following line to the first item in the chain:

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
```

[image]

To read more about chain styles:

- [Official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#chain-style)
- [Medium article](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html)